# How to prove this theorem on diagonalizable operator on finite dimensional Vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, diagonalization, direct-sum, invariant-subspace

**Question**: let $T$ be linear operator on finite dimensional Vector space $V$ then $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $V$ is direct sum of one dimensional $T$-invariant subspaces.

**My attempt**: if $T$ is diagonalizable linear operator on $n$ dimensional Vector space $V$ then $V$ has basis say $\beta =\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ consisting of an eigenvectors of $T$.

Taking $W_i=span\{v_i\}$ where $i=1,..,n$ then

$W_i ∩Wj=\{0\}$ for $i≠j$  and $V=W_1+...+W_n$.

Hence  $V=W_1⊕...⊕W_n$ i.e. $V$ is direct sum of one dimensional $T$ invariant subspaces.

I had skip to prove $W_i$ are $T$ invariant but I think it's obvious by definiition of $W_i$.

**Is above proof is valid? In fact I saw the above question/ theorem first time. Is the statement of above theorem is correct?**

Please help me.

Comment: No, you are asked to prove an equivalence  and you attemped only one direction. The implication you started with is correct though. $W_i$ is T-invariant because these spaces are generated by eigenvectors. So, include your attempt for the converse.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Thanks. :-)